# Move SOME Vagrant boxes to external drive

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a number of projects that use Vagrant and associated VMs.  Some are in current development, others are either in maintenance or archived, and I do not need the latter on my laptop.  256GBs fill up fast.

What I'd like to do is move the archived and maintenance virtual machines to an external SSD hard drive, but still have them accessible via the Vagrant command line.

All google queries and searches have only turned up a permanent move to another drive, and nothing about some here and some there.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use [environment variables](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/environmental-variables.html) for change location setting

i think that may help.

use it in this way `VAR="C:\some_location" vagrant up`

```
VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH
VAGRANT_HOME
```

VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH can be set to change the directory where Vagrant stores VM-specific state, such as the VirtualBox VM UUID. By default, this is set to .vagrant. If you keep your Vagrantfile in a Dropbox folder in order to share the folder between your desktop and laptop (for example), Vagrant will overwrite the files in this directory with the details of the VM on the most recently-used host. To avoid this, you could set VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH to .vagrant-laptop and .vagrant-desktop on the respective machines. (Remember to update your .gitignore!)